# How to fix the No implementation for play.api.db.DBApi was bound. with play 2.8.13

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick, play-slick

we are upgrading the tech stack versions of my project due to log4j vulnerability.
**SBT 1.6.2,
Scala 2.13.6,
play_scala 2.8.13**
I used  below dependencies to connect database and I mentioned db configurations in `application.conf` file.Also using `customApplicationLoader.scala` file

```
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "5.0.0",
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1206-jdbc42",
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "5.0.0" % Test

   
import play.api.ApplicationLoader
import play.api.inject.guice.{GuiceApplicationLoader, GuiceApplicationBuilder}
class CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {
override protected def builder(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): GuiceApplicationBuilder = {
super.builder(context).disableCircularProxies(true)
}
}
```

but I'm facing the below issue
[image: issue screen shot]

How can I resolve this please suggest here. Thank you

Comment: Does this happen when you try to run application from IntelliJ? If so, sometimes I got this random error when I rebuild application and I fix it by running sbt shell within IntelliJ and run tests... I don't know how that's working but it helps in my case.

Of course this might help only if db binding was working before but it's not anymore even so you haven't touched it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, After adding `libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-guice" % "2.8.15"` dependency and adding below configurations in **application.conf** my issue resolved.

```
play.evolutions.enabled = false
play.evolutions.db.default.autoApply = true
play.modules.disabled += "play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule"
```